# KeyUp event not firing for combobox

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, combobox

I have an ajax combo box, the goal is to update the drop down list items as the user is entering text. I am trying to fire an `onkeyup` event for this combo box so as the client releases the key a code behind function is called and updates the items.

```
cc1:ComboBox ID="Address_Enter" runat="server" Width="492px"    
DropDownStyle="DropDown" AutoCompleteMode="Suggest" AutoPostBack="true" 
OnSelectedIndexChanged="SetSelectedAddress"> 
</cc1:ComboBox
```

using a the following JS/Ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () { $("#Address_Enter").keyup(UpdateDropdown); alert("JS worked on load"); })
        $("#Address_Enter").on('change',function(e){UpdateDropdown();});

            function UpdateDropdown() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Default.aspx/Address_enter_TextChangedEvent",
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                })
        alert("JS worked");
    };

</script>
```

However the event is not firing when the user presses a key. Please advise.

Comment: Can you also post the HTML markup? It's possible that you're not finding the correct element to attach the JQuery event to

Comment: In the effort of the process of elimination, verify that you are indeed POSTing to the URL you specified. Add `error` to your aJax call, [as such](https://jsfiddle.net/6vvxay1p/).

Comment: If the combobox is an asp.net user control, I think you'll find the id is rewritten when the control is rendered. In jQuery, you sould reference it by `ClientId`

Comment: Hello and thank you, I will definitely take a look at the reference for the combobox, it is in asp user control.

Comment: Johnathan was correct, the client id needed to be set to static. Now the JS is working but the method defined in the code behind is not firing.

Comment: @JWheelr just a side note, you're attaching two event listeners (keyup and onchange) to `#Address_Enter`. This will cause `UpdateDropdown()` getting called twice every time a user types a character. Not sure if that's your intended behavior.